# Why is ToolTipManager.sharedInstance.registerComponent(tree) is not done automatically ?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtree

i am new on this site and please correct me if the way i am asking is wrong.

As the question above, why `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance.registerComponent`(tree) does not done automatically in the `Swing`? Is it because of performance issues or it is not designed to be used with `JTree` ?

Comment: Is it done automatically for other components?

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips work perfectly well with [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html). In particular, a `JTree` may have "a [different tooltip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html) based on where the mouse is." Registration enables [`getToolTipText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getToolTipText%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) to "properly display tooltips of its renderers." See [*How to Use Trees: Customizing a Tree's Display*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) for details.

Answer (score 1):

as the question is "why not": (can only guess of course, wasn't there :) most probably there is no reason, just an oversight. Getting there by comparison with the other collection components (aka: JTable, JList) which *do* register themselves on init.